# I am a Syrian citizen. I am going to Lebanon, transitioning in Istanbul from UK

Tags: transit, istanbul, us-residents, syrian-citizens, pegasus-airlines

I am a Syrian citizen  holding a Green Card from the USA . I am going to Lebanon, transiting in Istanbul (SAW) from UK on Pegasus flight. Will I need a transit visa to change flight in Instanbul?

Comment: Is this booking on a single ticket?

Comment: yes it is on the same carrier on the same ticket

Comment: How long is your transit? I think you can most probably TWOV, you can check by entering your trip details in Timatic (the system used by airlines) https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true and/or the IATA Travel Centre https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/